# How to remove a number of same positve and negative from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using useState hooks and when I click on the button of input value it updated my state and adds new elements in the array. I want to implement this here when I click the same value of positive and negative number both of the same number should be removed from the array
For Example when I click on a button and elements are added,  if I add 3 and after -3 both of the number should be removed from the array as shown in the example

[-3, 1, 2, 3, 4] = [1, 2, 4]

Help me for solving this problem

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");

  const onDataSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setData([...data, number]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="container1">
          <div className="input">
            <input
              id="title"
              type="number"
              value={number}
              onChange={(event) =>                      
                  setNumber(event.target.value)}
              name="title"
              placeholder="Title"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <button className="btn" onClick={onDataSubmit}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="container2">{data.sort((a, b) => a - b)}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If positive number

```js
// new number is 3
[-3,1,2] => [1,2]
```

If negative number

```js
// new number is -2
[-3,1,2] => [-3,1]
```

```js
const onDataSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const absNumber = Math.abs(number);
  // both check if number is positive or negative
  if (
    data.find(
      (n) => Math.abs(n) === absNumber || -Math.abs(n) === -absNumber
    ) === undefined
  )
    return setData([...data, number]);
  
  // if number is not in the array add the new number
  setData((prevData) => {
    return prevData.filter(
      (n) => Math.abs(n) !== absNumber || -Math.abs(n) !== -absNumber
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on the previous submissions, this one below checks for all edge cases, and tries to reduce on loops too.
so with that said:-

```js
const update_data = num => {
    if (!data.includes(num) && !data.includes(Math.abs(num)*-1) && !data.includes(Math.abs(num))) {
        setData([...data, num])
    } else {
        setData(data.filter(y => y + num !== 0))
    }
}
```

Results of running the above given the following array:-

```js
let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -8]
```

Input 8 --- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Input -1 -- [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -8]

Input 2 --- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -8]

Input 9 --- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -8, 9]

Hopefully you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    let array = [-3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    let positiveArray=array.map(n=>Math.abs(n))
    let newData = positiveArray.filter((n, i,a) => {
      let arr = [...positiveArray];
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      return !(arr.includes(n));
    })
console.log(newData); // [1,2,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setData(prev => 
  prev.reduce((val, item) => {
    if (item + number !== 0) {
      val.push(item);
    } else {
      val.splice(0, 1);
    }
    return val;
  }, [number])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const onDataSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const newData = [...data];   
    const index = newData.indexOf(number * -1);
  
    if (index !== -1) {
      newData.splice(index, 1);
      setData(newData);
      
      return
    }
    
    setData([...data, number])
  };
```

**number * -1** will change the sign to it's opposite (- to + and + to -)